# Open the app that is related to background task from the background task windows phone 8/8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, scheduled-tasks

I am very new to Scheduled tasks in Windows Phone, now I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight) app that runs a background task and and on meeting some particular condition, it should automatically opens the main app page (MainPage). Is this possible? if yes, how to make this done?

Comment: If you want to open the MainPage by yourself (with no user interaction) I need to say it is not possible. But you can show to him a toast notification and if the user click it it open the MainPage.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I will work on it.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not a WP developer but a fan. I've already used more than 600 apps and none of them did what you want. So I start from the principle that you can't. On the other side the example I gave is used a lot. If you use twitter a recomend you ask with the #wpdev. They usually respond quickly.